# Tasks or Threads for a long-running operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a windows service that runs two methods; one uses the `Ae.Net.Mail` library to read unread emails from three email accounts every 5 minutes (let's call it EmailParserWorker), and the other method makes another unspecified job every 30 minutes. Because these methods have to be run every X amount of time, I use a `Timer` to manage them, and they work fine.

```
private Timer mailParserTimer;
private readonly TimeSpan SLEEP_TIME_MAIL_PARSER = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300d);

/*...*/

public MyService()
{
    ServiceName = _serviceName;
    mailParserTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(EmailParserWorker), null, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}
public void StartService()
{
    mailParserTimer.Change(SLEEP_TIME_MAIL_PARSER, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    //EmailAnalyzer is a custom class I use to manage the accounts
    ea1 = new EmailAnalyzer(Config1); 
    ea2 = new EmailAnalyzer(Config2); 
    ea3 = new EmailAnalyzer(Config3); 
}

protected void EmailParserWorker(object state)
{
    try
    {
        // Pause timer during processing so it won't be run twice if the processing takes longer than the interval
        mailParserTimer.Change(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);

        // MANAGE THE THREE EMAIL ACCOUNTS
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("[EmailParserWorker] Exception caught:" + ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
    }

    // Launch again in the specified time
    mailParserTimer.Change(SLEEP_TIME_MAIL_PARSER, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}
```

The question I have is when I have to manage the three email accounts. My manager asked me to use threads so that they can run at the same time, and after investigating a bit about `Threads` and `Tasks`, I'm confused as to which is my best option. I know `ThreadPooling` is out of the question, since I read somewhere that those shouldn't be used if the operation will last more than a couple seconds (which mine certainly will); but doesn't `Task` use this functionality? I know it has a LongRunning option, but I don't know if my process qualifies as one. And then there's `Threads`, which should be able to handle this without problem, but I don't know if it'll be incredibly inefficient in terms of CPU usage.

Basically, I don't know which one of these I should use. For now I'm leaning towards `Tasks`, but I don't know if I should specify the LongRunning token. And also, if relevant, does the fact that these threads or tasks will be running inside a method using timer affect anything at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`LongRunning` effectively means "always start a new thread right now". This is not documented but for compatibility reasons this behavior can never change.

You should use `Task` and `LongRunning`. This is strictly superior to `Thread`. Especially error handling and composition are much better.

Starting and destroying a thread is a matter of milliseconds. Like 1ms or so. Don't worry about starting 3 threads.

> does the fact that these threads or tasks will be running inside a method using timer affect anything at all?

They will *not* be running in the timer method. The timer method will start the task which is a quick operation. Timer tick callbacks run on the thread-pool. This is not a concern here because you are offloading the work to dedicated threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But for the sake of future instances, you say that `LongRunning` means "always start a new thread right now"; what does this mean for Tasks that do not use this token? I'm still a little confused about its meaning.

Comment: Those tasks will be queued to the thread-pool. It's heuristics are not well defined or understood. If the pool has a lot of work queued then it might take a long time to start new items. If the pool is idle new items start immediately. It's complicated...

Comment: `LongRunning` means new thread only for default task scheduler. Any other task scheduler free to ignore this option, as it is not requirement, but just a hint. For example synchronization context task scheduler `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` ignore it and just use `Post` method from captured synchronization context.

Comment: I guess I'll have to keep investigating on my own; but for my current problem this will do, so thank you.